# Cómo descargar un archivo de servidor sftp con spring batch y leerlo para insertarlo en la base de datos

Tags: java, spring, archivo

He creado un Tasklet que se conecta al servidor sftp y descargo el archivo, pero mi código aún no funciona cuando lo paso al lector de elementos, ya que me dice "Error al inicializar el lector" visualizando mi IDE, el archivo aparece en la ruta al final de la ejecución "El recurso de entrada debe existir (el lector está en modo 'estricto'): recurso de ruta de clase [hi.csv]"

my Tasklet class :

```
public class giveMeTheFile implements Tasklet {


    private static final String USERNAME = "seenisftp";
    private static final String HOST = "172.17.56.250";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "shenlong";
    private static final String PATH = "upload/test.csv";
    private static final String LOCALDIR = "src/main/resources/";
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(giveMeTheFile.class);
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(giveMeTheFile.class);


    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {


        SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
        client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
        LOG.info("Connecting to server..." + HOST);
        client.connect(HOST);

        LOG.info("verify.." + USERNAME);
        LOG.info("verify.." + PASSWORD);
        client.authPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        LOG.info("successful connection");
        SFTPClient sftpClient = client.newSFTPClient();
        LOG.info("searching file....");
        sftpClient.get(PATH, LOCALDIR + "hi.csv ");
        LOG.info("file get successfully" + LOCALDIR + sftpClient);
        sftpClient.close();
        client.disconnect();


        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

my item reader:

```
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Pagare> fileItemReader(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Pagare> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper)  {

        FlatFileItemReader<Pagare> fileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        fileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        fileItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("hi.csv"));
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames("numeroPagare", "numeroContrato", "numeroOperacion", "rutCliente", "fechaOtorgamiento", "marca", "vehiculo", "version", "modelo", "montoFinanciar", "impuesto");
        DefaultLineMapper<Pagare> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);
        fileItemReader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);
        return fileItemReader;
    }
```

mi paso que llama al tasklet:

```
   @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(new giveMeTheFile())
                .build();
    }
```

mi paso del flujo de lectura, proceso y escritura:

```
    public Step step4(ItemReader<Pagare> reader, ItemWriter<Pagare> writer, ItemProcessor<Pagare, Pagare> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step4")
                .<Pagare, Pagare> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(1)
                .skip(FlatFileParseException.class)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

mi trabajo que llama a los pasos:

```
    public Job DownloadFile(Step step1, Step step2, Step step4) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("DownloadFile")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .start(step1)
                .next(step4)
                .build();

    }
```

No entiendo lo que estoy haciendo mal si hice el tasklet con la conexión y la descarga del archivo ... porque la descarga no está completa al final del tasklet? Según la documentación oficial, el tasklet se usa para tareas antes de la ejecución, la descarga del archivo solo se muestra en el directorio al finalizar el codigo y lo necesito antes para que mi metodo de lectura pueda procesarlo

Comment: ¿SFTPClient es una clase de alguna librería conocida?

Comment: es de la  libreria sshj